# idiom for auto-initializing map values to 0

Tags: dart

Is there a better idiom for auto-initializing Map values to 0 than the following? In the following code there is an asymmetry between the approach to **adding** a value to a target of type *List* versus *int*.

```dart
main() {
  addToList(Map m, v) =>
    m..putIfAbsent('foo', () => []).add(v);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Not allowed (expression is not assignable)
  // addToScalar(Map m, v) =>
  //   m..putIfAbsent('foo', () => 0) += 3;

  addToScalar1(Map m, v) {
    m.putIfAbsent('foo', () => 0);
    m['foo'] += v;
    return m;
  }

  addToScalar2(Map m, v) {
    if(m.containsKey('foo')) {
      m['foo'] += v;
    } else {
      m['foo'] = v;
    }
    return m;
  }

  print(addToList({}, 3));
  print(addToScalar1({}, 3));
  print(addToScalar2({}, 3));
}
```

Conceptually *addToList* and *addToScalar* do similar things. But the analog for the int stored as a value type might be:

```
m.putIfAbsent('foo', () => 0) += someValue
```

which will not work since what is returned from *putIfAbsent* is not assignable. So with both the working approaches used in the scalar case the lookup in the map for key *'foo'* is being done twice. Can this be avoided with the Map API?

Comment: You could of course create a subclass of the Map class that overrides add()...

Comment: Yes - but the versions I've seen still just wrap an internal Map for delegation and the issue/question remains. If _addToScalar1_ is the way to do it - I'm fine with that. But I just want to know if that is a good idiom or is there something better in the api. Also looking for insight into the fundamental difference between the list and int examples. I imagine there would be no issue if int had a method called _plusEquals_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot currently avoid two lookups in order to modify a map value.

We have considered, but never decided on, a way to achieve that (e.g., an "update" method).

The Two shortest/most efficient solution to your problem are:

```
int _returnZero() => 0; // Toplevel or static function.

...  
  map[key] = map.putIfAbsent(key, _returnZero) + v;
...
```

and:

```
int value = map[key];
map[key] = (value == null) ? v : value + v;
```

Comment: Is there a dartbug filed for this feature ?